# What are the general techniques that allow for a HTTP page to respond to new information on a server (meta refresh, polling, etc)?

Tags: websocket, http2, spdy, quic

I'm looking for a timeline of historic to modern approaches to updating client side content.

Take for example the process of ordering, preparing, and delivering a pizza.  What are the various techniques that are possible to update client side state?

So far I have

- Meta Refresh (ancient)
- Javascript polling
- Websockets
- Quic
- Spdy
- HTTP/2 implementation of SPDY

Do other techniques exist? If so what are they?

Answer (score 0):

**Streams**

[Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) for Javascript is the most modern way for a webpage to subscribe and be notified from a server. It is built using the **stream** concept in HTTP/2 (SPDY related) and [the stream concept](https://http3-explained.haxx.se/en/feature-streams.html) in HTTP/3 (QUIC related).

There are some protocols built on top of these concepts, e.g. [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) and [RSocket](http://rsocket.io/)